# Flattening a binary tree to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-tree

I found [this code](http://commoninterview.com/Programming_Interview_Questions/write-a-function-which-will-flatten-a-binary-tree-into-an-array/) for flattening a binary tree into array in Java. I am having hard time understanding how it works.

Here is the code:

```
private static int FlattenTreeIntoArray(Node tree, int[] array, int i)
{
    if (tree == null) return i;
    // Flatten left subtree
    i = FlattenTreeIntoArray(tree.Left, array, i);
    // Get data from the current node
    array[i] = tree.Data;
    // Flatten right subtree
    i = FlattenTreeIntoArray(tree.Right, array, i + 1);
    return i;
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. This is the helper method, how is the real method actually called, or what is passed as parameters (`int[] array` and `int i`)? We do not know the size of binary tree.
2. How does the method work? When the `tree` is `null`, it returns `i`. What does that mean?
3. How does the flattening happen? Why `i+1` is passed to `right tree` but `i` to `left tree`?

If you could demonstrate with this binary tree, it will be easy to follow:
[image: example binary tree (8 (3 1 (6 4 7)) (10 - (14 13 -)))]

Comment: For reference, the tree will basically be flattened to a list of ints representing the data from an inorder traversal.  This alone won't be enough info to reconstruct the tree exactly; you'd need additional info for that.

Comment: `i`  is the place in the array where the next element goes. The algorithm needs to know the number of elements in the tree to work without throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Usually, you would have a Tree.size() method or something that gives you that number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple recursive example, once you understand this, all recursive tree algorithms should begin to make sense.  I will try to answer your questions as best I can:

**This is the helper method, how is the real method actually called, or what is passed as parameters to int i and int[] array -- we do not know the size of binary tree**

Looking at the code, and since this is an interview type question, we will assume that the int[] array is big enough to fit everything.

`i` appears to be the current index of the array to populate so the first call to flatten the tree will be to set `i` to 0.

This method also returns an integer which is the number of elements that have been populated so far.  This means that the final return will return the full length of the tree (and the number of elements populated in the array)

```
int[] array = new int[size];
Node root = ...
int bytesWritten = FlattenTreeIntoArray(root, array, 0);

//bytesWritten should equal size
assert(bytesWritten == size);
```

**How does the method function: when the tree is null, it returns i. what does that mean?**

This assumes that a `Node`'s left or right fields point to null if there is no child.  Since we are using `i` to maintain where we are in the array, if there is no child, we don't update the value of `i`.

**how does the flattening happens? why i+1 is passed to right tree but i to left tree.**
  The flattening happens by finding the left most node and putting it in `i`.  Then finding the next most left node and putting it in `i+1` etc.

Let's walk through the tree example you gave:

node= 8
i =0;
array = {}

get left node of root, which is 3 and recursively call this flatten method, which gets the left node of 3 which is 1 and recursively calls the flatten method again, when gets the left node of 1 which is null. returns `i` = 0. 
Now we are in the flatten method for Node 1 `array[0] = Node 1's value` = `array[0] = 1.

Now call node 1's right field and flatten that incrementing i.  Node 1's right field is null so we return the current value of i (which is 1).

Now we are back in node 1's flatten method and have finsished recurssing the left and right and have reached the end of the method so we return the current value of `i` which is 1.

Now we are back in the flatten method for node 3.  We have just finished calling the flatten method for the left field which returned a value of 1 which is now what we set i to.

Now we update the array with node 3's value

```
array[1] = 3;
```

Now we flatten Node 3's right field (Node 6) with the incremented i so `i=2`

etc

Hope that helps

Comment: let say we have a tree with Three nodes, root and its right and left child. if I want to put them in array, left.data` will occupy `index 0`, `root.data` will occupy `index 1` and `right.data` will occupy `index 2`. so the left and right nodes, changes by two indices, but we do only 1+1 in the above code, why is that?

Comment: as per one of the comments above, I cannot reconstruct binary tree from this array, so does it mean I have to do a pre-order traversal

Comment: @user1988876 I'm not sure I understand your first question in the comment. If there are 3 nodes in the tree, the returned int (and final value of `i` is 3.  Because we return the `i+1` result from the right most child node's right field.  Even though this field is `null` we didn't know it until we looked.  And you are correct, the populated array is not the best way to reconstruct the binary tree from.  There are algorithms to do it though.  The interview question is more about do you understand recursion and binary trees.

Comment: @user1988876 Yes, pre-order would be ideal if you need to reconstruct. (Assumuing that the tree is indeed a binary search tree.)

Answer (score 25):

In addition to other answers, I made this gif to illustrate the execution of the algorithm. You see at the left the elements that have to be processed, and in the right the array.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice illustration. I see that it is a inorder traversal, but was my question was how the method functions. Others posts have explained them here. +1 for the gif.

Comment: @user1988876 Oh ok sorry :). Well that can be helpful for other people

Comment: @user2336315 where is the gif? :-P

Answer (score 3):

> This is the helper method, how is the real method actually called, or
>   what is passed as parameters to int i and int[] array -- we do not
>   know the size of binary tree

`int i` is the index in the array - you want to start with 0 as that is the first element. If you don't know the size of the tree, you are better off using a `LinkedList`

```
How does the method function: when the tree is null, it returns i. what does that mean?
```

It means you are checking a "child" that doesn't exist, so you return the index unchanged.

> how does the flattening happens? why i+1 is passed to right tree but i
>   to left tree.

You pass i to the left tree, because that call will pass back, by proof of recursion, the index in the tree where the data at the current node belongs. You must then tell the right tree that the index has increased, because by definition anything in the right tree will be of a higher value than the current node.

Your call would be `FlattenTreeIntoArray(my_tree, my_array, 0)` where `my_array.length == 9`

At the first call, the left subtree is root node `3`, which gets passed the index 0. After the call of the left subtree, the **new** left subtree is a leaf with data 1. When `FlattenTreeIntoArray` is called with **1** as the root, it will pass a null child to `FlattenTreeIntoArray` and thus return 0.

Your next call will be `my_array[0] = 1`, thus the first element of the array is the lowest number in the tree. It will then increment and return the index.

So eventually the call where the root is 3 will be returned `1` as the index, and will call `my_array[1] = 3`. So on and so forth, rinse and repeat.

Comment: how is the `node 6` assigned an index in array?

Comment: @user1988876 After the 3 is written, it'll do the right tree with index 2. Hence it will write 4 at 2. There is no right subtree of 4, hence 3 is returned. This is where 6 is written.

Comment: @user1988876 You really should add some System.out.println() to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty functional code (see [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming)). This type of tree traversal is called [in-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order).

## Let’s make some observations

1. The tree is just read, never rewritten to.
2. In each call, `i` is incremented just once, iff the current node is not null. `i` is never decremented.
3. `array` is only written to. The only write is on index `i`. No other operations are performed with `array` (except for passing its reference).
4. Current node data is written to `array` between processing the left subtree and the right subtree.
5. `i` increment takes place after each `array[i]` write, no other `i` increments are performed.

## Guessing the meaning of parameters

- `tree` is clearly the tree to be processed.
- The meaning of `i` is “index of the first (from left to right) empty position in `array`”. So it should be 0 at the beginning.
- After returning from the topmost call, `array` should contain the flattened tree. It is obvious that `array` is filled from left to right and has no chance to adjust its size. Therefore it should be initialized to a long enough empty array. If it is not long enough, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will get thrown somewhere down the recursion tree once `i` value exceeds its size.
- `FlattenTreeIntoArray(tree, array, i)` flattens `tree`, writes this in-order sequence of node values to `array`, starting at index `i`, and returns index of the first non-used position in `array`.

So the topmost call looks like:

```
// tree and MAX_TREE_SIZE come from outside
int[] array = new int[MAX_TREE_SIZE];
int tree_size = FlattenTreeIntoArray(tree, array, 0);
```

## Now let’s prove it

Go through these claims and prove them using the observations above and [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) over the program run (instruction sequence). That is all. I will not post details here as it is trivial but hard to describe really formally, so it would take much space. But I will happily answer any questions in comments and maybe edit my answer to include some of them.